# How to mark all dates in month calendar

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I know how to mark just one date like

```
monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = qwerDates;
```

but does any one know how to Bold all dates for example, I want to Bold January 1, what I mean January 1 is all the January 1's in all years from this current year  until year 9999

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ to create an array of `DateTime` objects, like this one that creates an instance for January 1st of each year from the current year to 9999.

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Year;

monthCalendar1.BoldedDates =
    Enumerable.Range(now, 10000 - now).Select(x => new DateTime(x, 1, 1)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! Just what I'm looking for